# Work permit for a US based space and defence company for EU citizen

Tags: united-states, germany, paperwork

I'm looking into writing my bachelor thesis at a aerospace company abroad.

---

**My question is if there are any special regulation regarding working for a aerospace company, with military contracts, as a student from Germany.**

---

The company in question is a US company with locations in other countries (non EU).

On their application page they state:

> For security reasons background checks will be undertaken prior to any employment offers being made to an applicant.  These checks will include nationality checks as it is a requirement of this position that you be eligible to access equipment and data regulated by the United States’ International Traffic in Arms Regulations.  Under these Regulations, you may be ineligible for this role if you do not hold citizenship of Australia, Japan, New Zealand, Switzerland, the European Union or a country that is part of NATO, or if you hold ineligible dual citizenship or nationality.

With my only nationality being German I fulfill the requirements.
Acquiring a visa for studying/working as a student for the company non US location is unproblematic. Additionally I already passed background checks for arms manufacture based in the EU in the recent past.

***Are there any additional "tripping hazards" which could prevent me working for the company?***

Comment: I assume it is clear, that a visa that permits **working** is needed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, there are special student visas which allow working, at least in NZ

Comment: But if you are working in the US, you are not a student. Or arre you enroled for the batelor in the US?